# ActiveRecord find all records including spesific foreign word (case insensitive)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I would like to write an ActiveRecord query to fetch all records which include specific foreign language words (case insensitive) in the `description` column of records table.

I think I can use `mb_chars.downcase` which converts international chars to lower case successfully.

```
> "ÖİÜŞĞ".mb_chars.downcase
=> "öiüşğ"
```

However, when I try to use `mb_chars.downcase` in ActiveRecord query I receive the following error:

```
def self.targetwords
  target_keywords_array = ['%ağaç%','%üzüm%','%çocuk%']
  Record.where('description.mb_chars.downcase ILIKE ANY ( array[?] )', target_keywords_array)
end

ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "mb_chars"
```

I will appreciate if you can guide me how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying too hard, you should let the database do the work. PostgreSQL knows how to work with those characters in a case-insensitive fashion so you should just let `ilike` deal with it inside the database. For example:

```
psql> select 'ÖİÜŞĞ' ilike '%öiüşğ%';
 ?column? 
----------
 t
(1 row)
```

You could say simply this:

```
def self.targetwords
  target_keywords_array = ['%ağaç%','%üzüm%','%çocuk%']
  Record.where('description ILIKE ANY ( array[?] )', target_keywords_array)
end
```

or even:

```
def self.targetwords
  Record.where('description ilike any(array[?])', %w[ağaç üzüm çocuk].map { |w| "%#{w}%" })
end
```

or:

```
def self.targetwords
  words   = %w[ağaç üzüm çocuk]
  likeify = ->(w) { "%#{w}%" }
  Record.where('description ilike any(array[?])', words.map(&likeify))
end
```

---

As far as why

```
Record.where('description.mb_chars.downcase ILIKE ANY ( array[?] )', ...)
```

doesn't work, the problem is that `description.mb_chars.downcase` is a bit of Ruby code but the string you pass to `where` is a piece of SQL. SQL doesn't know anything about Ruby methods or using `.` to call methods.